# apt-get trying to install from wine but wine has been uninstalled

Tags: apt, package-management, 17.04

While running `sudo apt-get update` I get the following output:

```
baal@baal-Aspire-5733Z:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for baal: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease      
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu zesty InRelease      
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease          
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages 
  404  Not Found
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages  
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 89.2 kB in 7s (11.6 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I've uninstalled wine with `sudo apt-get remove wine-stable --purge` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`. However it seems that `apt-get` is still trying to download from the `wine` source. How can I fix this?

Comment: @karel is OP trying install or uninstall wine? Confused here a bit.

Comment: @George sorry for the confusion, I want to stop apt-get from trying to install from that source

Comment: The OP is trying to remove the deprecated ppa:wine/wine-builds PPA from his software sources.

Comment: System Settings --> Software and Updates --> Other Software. Uncheck the PPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you added wine from a PPA.
It's not enough to uninstall the software - you must remove the source.

System Settings --> Software and Updates --> Other Software. 
Uncheck the PPA.